# Why are forward declarations not working in this case?

Tags: c++

Consider the following example:

`a.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "b.h"

enum class SActionType;

class A {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> my_bees;
public:
    A();
    void print(int x, int y);
};
#endif
```

`a.cc`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

A::A() {
}

void A::print(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << "hi this is not going to work" << std::endl;
}
```

`b.h`:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
// #include "a.h"

class A;
class B {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<A> a);
    void foo();
};
#endif
```

`b.cc`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include "b.h"

B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> a):
    a{a}
{}

void B::foo() {
    a->print(1, 2);
}
```

`main.cc`:

```cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
exec: main.o a.o b.o
    g++ -std=c++14 -o exec
main.o: main.cc
a.o: a.cc a.h
b.o: b.cc b.h
```

After running `make`, I get the following error:

```
me:~$ make
g++    -c -o b.o b.cc
b.cc: In member function ‘void B::foo()’:
b.cc:9:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘using element_type = class A {aka class A}’
     a->print(1, 2);
      ^~
In file included from b.cc:2:0:
b.h:8:7: note: forward declaration of ‘using element_type = class A {aka class A}’
 class A;
       ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'b.o' failed
make: *** [b.o] Error 1
```

Why is this happening? I thought that this would work because of class `B` does not actually need to access the member functions of A until the `.cc` files, and just having the forward declaration in the header file would be enough to circumvent the circular dependency.

Comment: `b.cc` needs a definition of `A` but doesn't have one.

Comment: @Mat But doing `#include a.h` will give a circular dependency. In what way can I solve this?

Comment: `b.cc` needs definitions of both `A` and `B`.  It `#include`s `b.h` which defines `B` but declares `A` without defining it.   It also needs to `#include  "a.h"` for the definition of `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that this would work because of class `B` does not actually need to access the member functions of `A` until the `.cc` files

That's correct. `b.h` does not need to include `a.h` (nor does `a.h` need to include `b.h`). But `b.cc` needs to include both. Nothing circular about that. After all, `a.cc` does the same thing.

`b.cc`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> a):
    a{a}
{}

void B::foo() {
    a->print(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to know the complete type of the class A that to check for example that this construction

```
void B::foo() {
    a->print(1, 2);
}
```

is valid that is that the class A contains the member function (static or non-static?) `print`.